# NSManagedObject unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject, nsorderedset

I have a Core Data model as follows, where children is a to-many relationship.

.h

```
@implementation MyEntity

@dynamic name;
@dynamic children;

@end
```

.m

```
@interface MyEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSOrderedSet *children;

@end
```

I then try to set it using:

```
        MYAppDelegate *delegate = (MYAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *categoryEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *newCategory = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:categoryEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [newCategory setValue:key forKey:@"name"];
        NSOrderedSet *testSet = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:@[@"This", @"is", @"a", @"test"]];
        [newCategory setValue:testSet forKey:@"children"];
    }
}
```

Yet on that last line, I get this error:

> NSCFConstantString managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0xe8fa0'

If I change `NSOrderedSet` to `NSSet` the compiler complains that it expects an `NSOrderedSet`.

How can I assign the set to the `NSManagedObject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't the `NSOrderedSet`, its the `NSString` instances that you put inside the set. These need to be replaces with instances of the entity which is configured in the data model at the destination of the relationship. You can't fill the relationship with the wrong kind of object.

Comment: The `NSManagedObject` represents a category. The category has a to-many relationship to itself, because I'm using a recursive hierarchy of categories. It seems then that elements of the `NSOrderedSet` should be instances of `MyEntity`. But how can I create those objects and children? Do I need to use an algorithm that populates the child entities first?

Comment: As this is a test just `alloc] initWithEntity:categoryEntity` a new instance of your entity and put that in the set.