# Core data: The entity is not key value coding for the key

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have six entities in my xcdatamodeld. Article, Section, References, Bookmarks, BookmarkReferences and BookmarkSections. I am trying to save the bookmarked articles separately to the Bookmarks entity. The Article has inverse set to Sections and References similarly Bookmarks has inverse set to BookmarkReferences and BookmarkSections. When i try to set the values from Article NSManagedObject to Bookmarks NSManagedObj i am getting KVC error. I have made sure that there are no typos in the key names. Have a look at the code and log.

```
 extension Bookmarks {
     @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Bookmarks> {
         return NSFetchRequest<Bookmarks>(entityName: "Bookmarks");
     }
     @NSManaged public var id: String?
     @NSManaged public var status: String?
     @NSManaged public var createdBy: String?
     @NSManaged public var articleType: String?
     @NSManaged public var modifiedBy: String?
     @NSManaged public var tag: String?
     @NSManaged public var sendNotification: Bool
     @NSManaged public var bookmark: Bool
     @NSManaged public var isRead: Bool
     @NSManaged public var isArticleFromSearch: Bool
     @NSManaged public var searchString: String?
     @NSManaged public var isArticleFromCategory: Bool
     @NSManaged public var modifiedDate: String?
     @NSManaged public var createdDate: String?
     @NSManaged public var category: String?
     @NSManaged public var subCategory: String?
     @NSManaged public var title: String?
     @NSManaged public var general: NSDictionary?
     @NSManaged public var bookmarkSections: NSSet?
     @NSManaged public var bookmarkReferences: NSSet?
}

extension BookmarkSections {
    static func saveSectionsForBookmarks(entity: Article, privateContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSSet {
        let sections = entity.sections
        let sectionED = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "BookmarkSections", in: privateContext)
        let sectionMO = NSManagedObject(entity: sectionED!, insertInto: privateContext)
        let sectionsSet = NSMutableSet()
        let allSectionItems = sections?.allObjects
        for (_, sectionItem) in (allSectionItems?.enumerated())! {
            let castedSection = sectionItem as? Sections
            sectionMO.setValue(castedSection!.id, forKey: "id")
            sectionMO.setValue(castedSection!.text, forKey: "text")
            sectionMO.setValue(castedSection!.imageUrl, forKey: "imageUrl")
            sectionMO.setValue(castedSection!.imageName, forKey: "imageName")
            sectionMO.setValue(castedSection!.title, forKey: "title")
            sectionsSet.add(sectionMO)
        }
        return sectionsSet
    }
}
[`    
extension Bookmarks {
    public static func saveToNew(Entity: Article) {
    let managedContext = CoreDataStorage.sharedInstance.privateQueueContext
    let entityDesc =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Bookmarks",
                                   in: managedContext)!
    let articleMO = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDesc,
                                  insertInto: managedContext)
    articleMO.setValue(Entity.id, forKey: "id")
    articleMO.setValue(Entity.status, forKey: "status")
    articleMO.setValue(Entity.createdBy, forKey: "createdBy")
    articleMO.setValue(Entity.articleType, forKey: "articleType")
    articleMO.setValue(Entity.modifiedBy, forKey: "modifiedBy")
    let isSendNotification=NSNumber(value: false)     
    articleMO.setValue(isSendNotification, forKey: "sendNotification")

    let modifiedDate = String(describing: Entity.modifiedDate)
    articleMO.setValue(modifiedDate, forKey: "modifiedDate")

    let createdDate = String(describing: Entity.createdDate)
    articleMO.setValue(createdDate, forKey: "createdDate")

    articleMO.setValue(Entity.category, forKey: "category")
    articleMO.setValue(Entity.subCategory, forKey: "subCategory")

    let general = NSMutableDictionary()
    let dict = Entity.general

    for (key,subJson):(Any, Any) in dict! {
        general.setValue(subJson as! String, forKey: key as! String)
    }
    articleMO.setValue(general, forKey: "general")

    articleMO.setValue(Entity.title, forKey: "title")

    articleMO.setValue(BookmarkSections.saveSectionsForBookmarks(entity: Entity, privateContext: managedContext), forKey: "bookmarkSections")

    articleMO.setValue(Entity.references, forKey: "references")
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}    
`]
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: There seems to be no property `bookmarkSections`in the entity `Bookmarks` in core data.

Comment: try changing type of `bookmarkSections` to NSMutableSet from NSSet.

Comment: @LoVo thank you that fixed the KVC issue. But now it gives me this error. "2017-07-31 15:26:51.683 Knappily[54319:24451155] -[__NSSetM managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000005bb70". bookmarkssection is of the type NSSet. not sure what is causing the issue.

Comment: did you try changing its data type?

Comment: @Priyal yes i tried changing it, but it didn't help.

Comment: Now the error looks like the problem in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073716/nsmanagedobject-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance

Comment: @LoVo The issue was because i forgot to set the relationship between the entities.